# Check File encoding (UTF-8/ANSI) in AIX Machine

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I need to convert file encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI format on AIX machine, iconv works but need to check the file encoding before conversion? I am looking for some options that I can add a condition to on top the iconv command. Convert the file only if its in UTF-8 encoding.

iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 abc.dat > abc_new.dat

Comment: Would the `file` utility help? I've used it on AIX systems.

Comment: @Hassam : What **exactly** would you like to check before conversion?

Comment: @Cole Tierney: I have tried file -I, file -bi but not working for AIX version.

Comment: If you don't trust your data-source, then you can try something like this: `iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 source.txt >target.txt 2>/dev/null || cp source.txt target.txt`

Comment: @user1934428 : Need to check if file is in UTF8 encoding then convert it to ansi else do not convert.

Comment: Unless you have a MIME-type from somewhere, I don't think that there is a foolproof way to understand the intended encoding. If you have a string of bytes, which happens to be valid under two different encodings, but with different meaning, there is no way you can recognize it. Some characters in ANSI are illegal in UTF8, and vice versa, and if your input happens to contain such a chararacter, you can at least distinguish between those cases. If the file was encoded by UTF-8, is it guaranteed at least that it contains a BOM?